# How do I add custom scripts in my package.json

Tags: npm, deployment, package.json, npm-scripts

I want to add a custom command called `deploy` which takes in an argument (AU/EU/US/NZ). I have 4 instances of my app 1 in AU, 1 in NZ, 1 in US, 1 in EU - Germany. When I want to deploy my app I have to do these 3 things:

1. Change a few constants in my code
2. Execute `npm run build`
3. scp my files to my desired server:/location

What I want to do instead is basically run a command like `npm run deploy --region=AU` and automatically do all 3 steps.

This will actually save me a lot of time (10-15 minutes) every time I have to deploy an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by adding 5 new properties to my `package.json`. Each of these properties holds info about different api/static URLs, site settings for that instance etc.

4 of the 5 instances are for one of each region and 1 of them is the selected one, so I have `AU`, `US`, `NZ`, `DEMO` and `SELECTED`.

Next I created a `deploy.js` file and added this code:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const saveFile = require('fs').writeFileSync;
let json = require("./package.json")
json["SELECTED"] =  json[process.argv[2]]
saveFile("./package.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, 2))
if (process.argv[2] == "NZ") exec("npm run build && sshpass -p 'password of server here' scp -r ./build/* user@host:/path/to/site/root/")
if (process.argv[2] == "AU") exec("npm run build && sshpass -p 'password of server here' scp -r ./build/* user@host:/path/to/site/root/")
if (process.argv[2] == "US") exec("npm run build && sshpass -p 'password of server here' scp -r ./build/* user@host:/path/to/site/root/")
if (process.argv[2] == "DEMO") exec("npm run build && sshpass -p 'password of server here' scp -r ./build/* user@host:/path/to/site/root/")
```

Next I added the following line tom my `scripts` object in the `package.json`:

```
"deploy": "node ./deploy.js"
```

To execute the deployment script and deploy on my AU server I need to:

```
npm run deploy AU
```

Same is for all other servers, just need to change the identifier from AU to one of the others specified in the `deploy.js` file. Effectively reduced the number of time it takes me to deploy by at least 15 minutes which is a lot since right now it takes me like 5 minutes instead of 20 - percentage wise its 75% time saved plus I have to write less commands in the terminal, I have to interact less with my code and it is mistake proof (mistakes like SCPing files to incorrect folder or on the wrong server).